# Wordpress WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT value is wrong in wp-config.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I was just looking at my wp-config.php file for my live wordpress site and I notice that the value for "WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT" is pointing to the old dev site (feedmybeta), not our live site.

What does this do and should I change it to the live site address? I'm scared to change it without understanding what it's doing.

Thanks!

The code looks like this -

```
/** Enable W3 Total Cache */
define('WP_CACHE', true); // Added by W3 Total Cache

define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', false);
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
$redis_server = array(
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'port'     => 6379,
    'database' => 0, // Optionally use a specific numeric Redis database. Default is 0.^M
);

define('WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT', 'flowersforeveryone.feedmybeta.com');
define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false);// This setting was defined by WordPress Toolkit to prevent WordPress auto-updates. Do not change it to avoid conflicts with the WordPress Toolkit auto-updates feature.^M
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://flowersforeveryone.co.za' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://flowersforeveryone.co.za' );
```

Comment: This isn't part of the native WP code so it presumably part of W3 Total Cache. Did you try their documentation or support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far as I know, WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT is not part of official WordPress, but a convention used by a variety of cache servers. Its value is essentially a site ID, and becomes important when several WordPress sites use the same cache server, to avoid cache collisions. If one site has the value of some other site, but the other site doesn't use that cache, collisions won't arise, so in theory all should be okay. But it could cause confusion, and is an accident waiting to happen, so it would be better to change the value. (And, yes, after the change, there would be a slow period while the cache fills again. That could probably be sidestepped if its critical.)